# Write a larger object over returned pointer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Given a function that returns a pointer to a float:

```
float* getFloatPointer();
```

How can I write an object that is not a float, and larger to the returned pointer? e.g. A Color class containing 3 floats. Something equivalent to this:

```
*getFloatPointer() = cast<float[3]>(Color); // Write 3 floats starting at position of returned pointer
```

I'm aware this could potentially be unsafe in general, and I can make several function calls setting the floats value one at a time, which is fine for my use. I'm mostly just curious after having thought about it.

Comment: This will call undefined behavior. Why for heaven's sake would you want to do so?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The OP says they're just curious.

Comment: `*getFloatPointer()` this will get you a single `float`, so your assignment could only ever be to that one `float`.

Comment: @JosephMansfield: How do you know the pointer only points to a single object? It could point to the start of an array, in which case this is a reasonable (if error-prone) thing to do.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I'm not disagreeing with the concept, just the idea the OP had. You can't have `something = whatever` and have it assign to anything other than `something`. They instead need to reinterpret the returned pointer as a pointer to `Color` and do the assignment.

Comment: In this case, the returned pointer does point to a color array. Of course, that array is not controlled by me, and the internals could be changed at any time. I'm not planning to do this for any practical purpose. I attempted to cast the returned pointer to a Color pointer, but I couldn't get the syntax right. At best I only got the red value being written.

Comment: @Weldon: Indeed, you can't assign arrays directly. You can capture the pointer and use `[]` to access the elements, or pass it to a function like `std::copy` to copy from another array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example illustrates what you're thinking about:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Color
{
    float r;
    float g;
    float b;
};

float array[3];

int main() {
    float* p = array;
    Color* cp = reinterpret_cast<Color*>(p);

    Color c = {1.0f, 0.5f, 0.25f};
    *cp = c;

    std::cout << p[0] << ' ' << p[1] << ' ' << p[2] << std::endl;
}
```

We reinterpret the returned `float*` as a `Color*`, and then assign to the object it points at. It works for me, but may not work for you.

Of course, this is in undefined behaviour territory, because it depends entirely on the layout of your `float` array and the `Color` struct. Basically, any time you use `reinterpret_cast`, you are telling the compiler to trust that you have a complete understanding of the machine code this will produce and the environment it will be executed in. You're saying "trust me, we can treat this `float*` as a `Color*`."

Comment: This is what I've essentially done, though I'm somehow writing (Red, 0, Some memory address). However, this example works for me, I'll check it against what I'm doing. It may be that the colour array is stored in a different manner than I'm expecting. Thanks. It's also good to know that it's undefined behaviour in any case. Edit: The mem address was just me missing a derefence.

Comment: It is also UB with strict aliasing rule.

Comment: @Jarod42 I believe the strict aliasing rule might make this legal only for the first member of `Color`, but since the layout of `Color` isn't guaranteed (particular padding between members), we still have undefined behaviour. You could, for example, do a `float* f = reinterpret_cast<float*>(&c)` and then do `*f = 0.5f;`.